# Quick check of all sub items in a List

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-2.0

I have a list with a boolean value as one of the properties.  I need to check if every one of these is true.  Now normally LINQ would give a nice clean answer here, but as I am using .NET 2.0 I can't use that.

If there a nicer way to do this or am I going to have to do a for each loop and break out on finding a false?

Edit:
Seems I could have been a bit clearer.  I have an object in a list (eg `List (Of MyObject)`).  There is a boolean property on this object called Processed.

I need to check that all objects in the list are processed.

So in LINQ I'd do:
`if (from o in list where o.processed = false select o).count = 0 then....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own generic list implementation an add a property IsProcessedCompletely:

```
 Public Class My_Class
        Public Property IsProcessed() As Boolean
            Get
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

    Public Class My_List
        Inherits List(Of My_Class)

        Public ReadOnly Property IsProcessedCompletely() As Boolean
            Get
                Dim enumerator As List(Of My_Class).Enumerator = MyBase.GetEnumerator
                While enumerator.MoveNext
                    If Not enumerator.Current.IsProcessed Then
                        Return False
                    End If
                End While
                Return True
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class
```

Comment: I sort of went with this, as it is only ever used in 1 place I just wrote a quick loop to check for it in a small function, didn't inherit. This is exactly what I was trying not to do but seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` and `List<T>` has a bunch of methods that does pretty much what LINQ does. They have been there before LINQ.

Specifically, look at the `Exists` method.  Unfortunately I dont know the VB syntax  :)

Comment: How would I perform the above then?  In LINQ I'd probably do a count of items that are false and check it's 0.  What would I do using the `List<T>` methods?

Answer (score 1):

By using `List<Of Boolean>` you can use `Contains()` method:

```
If MyList.Contains(false) Then
  // at least one false
Else
  // all true
End If
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't overly clear.  I have a `List(Of MyObject>` and a property of `MyObject` is a boolean.  I need to check that proprty, not a list of booleans.